# Search first row for certain text, then copy entire column

Tags: excel, vba, search, filter, rows

I'm fairly new to VBA and I'm having a lot of trouble doing a seemingly easy task. I've tried many different codes using this website and this is the one that gets me closest to what I want but it doesn't return any values. Here is the premise of what I need it to do:

1) Search the entire first row of columns (A1 to let's say Z1) of a worksheet for specific text such "Closed"

2) If the desired text "Closed" is found in one of the columns, copy all the values from that column

3) Paste those values from the column into Column J of another worksheet ("Source_Workbook")

****EDIT**: I want the column data to paste starting at the next empty row after row 5 of column J (10). I was having trouble using "Offset" in this case. Also, I want only the values to be pasted (keep the formatting of the page onto which the data is being pasted).

My problem is that this code keeps giving me errors when I try to do "Range.PasteSpecial." I hope I have the right approach. Please let me know if I can clarify anything further.

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Object
    Dim strMatch As String

    strMatch = "Closed" 'Search first row for columns with "Closed"
    Set rng = Target_Workbook2.Sheets(2).Range("A1:Z1")
    For Each cl In rng
        If cl.Value = strMatch Then
            cl.EntireColumn.Copy
            Exit For
            With Source_Workbook2.Sheets(2)
                Sheets(2).Columns("J").Offset(5, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End With
        End If
    Next cl
```

Would

```
    Target_Workbook2.Sheets(2).Range("A1:Z1").AutoFilter 1, "*Closed*"
```

possibly work better for filtering?

Comment: How can you even get to your .PasteSpecial when you do Exit For directly after you copy the row?

Comment: Along with dragonsamu's comment you call sheet(2) twice.  Once in the with statement and again right below.  Remove the second.  it should read .Columns("J").Off...

Comment: The answer below was helpful but didn't address the need to paste my data starting at the next empty row after the 5th row in Column J. I also want to only copy the values, not the formatting. Can you guys help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exiting for loop before pasting the values on Sheet2.
Try this code:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Object
Dim strMatch As String

strMatch = "Closed" 'Search first row for columns with "Closed"
Set rng = Target_Workbook2.Sheets(2).Range("A1:Z1")
For Each cl In rng
    If cl.Value = strMatch Then
        cl.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(10)
        Exit For
    End If
Next cl
```

**Edit 1**: Based on the comment
This will copy the column and paste it from row 5 on Sheet2.

```
Dim rng As range
Dim cl As Object
Dim strMatch As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim sh2lastrow As Long      '<--    Newly added
Dim col As Long                 '<--    Newly added
Dim range As range              '<--    Newly added

strMatch = "Closed" 'Search first row for columns with "Closed"
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row ' or + 1
sh2lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").range("J65536").End(xlUp).Row + 4     '<--    Newly added (Because you want to start from row 5)
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").range("A1:Z1")
For Each cl In rng
    If cl.Value = strMatch Then
        lastrow = Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count        '<--    (Getting row count of given column)
        col = cl.Column                                     '<--    (Getting column number of given column)
        With Sheets("Sheet1")
            Set range = .range(.Cells(2, col), .Cells(lastrow, col))        '<--    (Setting up the range to copy)
        End With
        range.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Activate       '<--    Newly added
        Sheets("Sheet2").range("J" & sh2lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues     '<--    (Pasting the copied data)
        sh2lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").range("J65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1     '<--    (Getting the last row from Sheet2)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    End If
Next cl
```

Comment: The OP states he was getting an error from .PasteSpecial, the For Exit was an issue yes but the real issue is that he incorrectly uses the With statement

Comment: Thank you very much! It works functionally, but I want the column data to paste starting at the next empty row after row 5 of column J (10). I was having trouble using "Offset" in this case. That's the last issue I need resolved. Also, I want only the values to be pasted (keep the formatting of the page onto which the data is being pasted).

Comment: Thank you for the follow up. The code is working but it is copying only the first two rows from the original sheet and pasting it into J8 and J9 of the destination sheet.

Comment: Focus `Sheet1` and then run this code. I've tested on my machine.

Comment: Still same result. I'm technically copying the data from one workbook and pasting it to another. But that shouldn't really affect the code right? As long as I use the appropriate extensions? For Each line of code involving "Sheets" I just put a TargetWorkbook.Sheets or DestinationWorkbook.Sheets to reference the correct workbook.

Comment: Even if you won't make those changes, it should work, as long as the sheets name are Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Comment: I still only have 2 rows copying. (The first two rows of the worksheet being copied, or "Sheet1"). Any idea why?

Comment: Just don't make any changes to the code, leave it as is and put it in a Sub (only this code and nothing else). Select Sheet1 and run the macro and update me what's happening.

Comment: There is no single reason to be using .Activate and should always be avoided. Properly reference to the Workbook and Worksheet

Comment: I did exactly as you said and it still only copies and pastes the first two rows. I feel like it has to do with the for each loop. The script is stopping running after two rows I think

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of your Sheet1 in your question?

Comment: This is proprietary information so I just made a similar looking sheet just with different "nonsense" values.
http://imgur.com/OGslm1a

Comment: That seems alright. Can you debug the code by pressing  `F8`.

Comment: Everything seems fine when debugging. It just only copies and pastes the first two rows of the column. Very odd...

Comment: Can you check what is the value of `lastrow` inside `For... Loop`...? And comment the first `lastrow` which is outside `For... Loop` (we don't need it).

Comment: It looks like the value for lastrow = Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count is 1. That would explain the problem. How do we fix it?

Comment: Debug and see what is the value for `col`, this column is where the script will find `Closed`. If its correct column, then that means something wrong in that column. I can't help you more without the seeing the actual data as I said, the script is working fine. Or may be create a dummy spreadsheet and upload it here.

Comment: Create a dummy spreadsheet and upload it here so that I can take a look.

Comment: There's no file upload service on this site.

Comment: I figured it out! It has to be `ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` not just `Cells`

Comment: Glad it worked. You can definitely use `CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` with `Cells`. In fact you can use `CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` with `Activesheet` as well.